# Where can I find instructions on how to install Vala on my Mac?

Tags: macos, vala

I'm looking into learn the Vala programming language where can I find somewhere to show me how to install it on my Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way to install it is to use [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/). MacPorts gives you access to Vala and many of the libraries often used with Vala.

Answer (score 16):

Another way to install it is using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

```
brew install vala
```

The advantage of Homebrew over Macports is that it tries to rely as much on what is provided by the native OS as possible without installing any additional duplicate libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) and it's installation instructions. There's a Vala plug-in for it.